# ¿Como subir un archivo modificado en github en un repositorio desde mi repositorio?

Tags: github

Cómo subo un archivo csv a github? soy nuevo en github.

Comment: Esto más parece una pregunta de git que de GitHub. GitHub es un servicio en la nube que proporcionana soporte con Git y git es un software de control de versiones

Answer (score 2):

**GUI**

Podes hacerlo a traves del GUI, anda a tu repositorio y vas a ver en la parte superior, por donde te muestra el listado de archivos, un boton que dice "Agregar Archivo", a la par de un boton verde. Ahi subis el archivo que queres guardar en tu repo.

**CLI**

Por otra parte, y la opcion mas recomendada de mi parte, es hacerlo a traves de la terminal. Primero te ubicas en el directorio en el que tenes tus archivos. Este directorio tiene que ser un directorio de git.

Si tu directorio no esta guardado con git, podes hacer dos cosas:

- Corres el comando `git init` en tu directorio, (asumiendo que tenes `git` instalado localmente), luego agregar la direccion de tu repositorio en github de la siguiente manera (reemplazando el url de tu repositorio):

```sh
git remote add origin <url-de-tu-repositorio>
```

Finalmente haces lo siguientes comandos: `git add .`, seguido de `git commit -m "<mensaje-que-querras-poner>"`, y finalmente `git push origin master`.

- Por otra parte, lo que podes hacer es descargar tu repositorio desde github localmente. Luego abris el directorio en tu terminal, moves el archivo `.csv` a ese directorio, y corres los tres comandos que te mencione anteriormente.